# Domain Filter is not working on many2many field in OpenERP 7.0

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8

I have added new many2many fields into the wizard view and also put invoice filed of many2many fields

**Field on py file :**

```
  'sup_inv_entries':fields.many2many('account.invoice', 'sup_inv_rel', 'sup_inv_id1', 'sup_new_inv_id', 'Invoice Entries'),
```

**Field on XML view file:**

```
 <field name="sup_inv_entries" nolabel="1" domain="['|',('period_id','in',period_ids),('&amp;',('date_invoice','&gt;',date_from),('date_invoice','&lt;',date_to)),'&amp;',('type','=','in_invoice'),('state','=','open')]">
```

I want to make the filter invoice ids based on periods or date_invoice (from date and to date ) based on user selected scenario from the wizard.